# pyqt - position child widget from qt designer near parent

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyside, qt-designer, pyqt5

I use `Qt Designer` to create a child widget (layout) - `tree_view_widget_ui.py`

```
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form, parent = None):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.setEnabled(True)
        Form.resize(200, 300)
        Form.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 300))
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
        self.treeWidget = QtGui.QTreeWidget(Form)
        self.treeWidget.setEnabled(True)
        self.treeWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 300))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        self.treeWidget.setFont(font)
        self.treeWidget.setDragDropMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.DragDrop)
        self.treeWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("treeWidget"))
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(0, _fromUtf8("1"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.treeWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Tree View", None))
        self.treeWidget.setSortingEnabled(True)
```

and I initialize child user-interface in `tree_view_widget.py`

```
from tree_view_widget_ui import Ui_Form

class TreeViewWidget(QWidget):
   def __init__(self, parent=None, flags=0):
       super(TreeViewWidget, self).__init__(parent)
       self.ui = Ui_Form()
       self.ui.setupUi(self, parent = parent)
```

And the child widget is intialized from parent `main.py` and opened with signal:

```
#    tree widget
from tree_view_widget.tree_view_widget import TreeViewWidget 

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.flags = QtCore.Qt.Window
        #    tree view widget
        self.TreeViewWidget = TreeViewWidget(parent=self)
        self.TreeViewWidget.setWindowFlags(self.flags)
        self.TreeViewWidget.show()
```

**My question is:** How can I position the child widget near parent widget that top left/right corners will coincide and not modifying file `tree_view_widget_ui.py` as this code is automatically generated from `Qt Designer`. I managed to position child widget to target location but only when modifying file `tree_view_widget_ui.py` but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `class MainWindow`:

You will want to use `self.TreeViewWidget.setGeometry(x, y, width, height)` or you could use the move(x, y) function.

See docs for [setGeometry](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#geometry-prop) and [move](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#pos-prop) functions

Comment: I've tried`move` in `tree_view_widget.py` and it was not working. As you suggested I used `move` in `class MainWindow` as the geometry of widget is defined in `tree_view_widget_ui.py`. It works!